# All button click functions point to the last id (except last button points to undefined) instead of pointing to its own id

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, express

I want to add a delete button that will delete that specific created "event" when it is clicked ("event" is what the user creates in the app).

Problem: if there are 10 events (id 1-10), clicking on buttons 1-9 will use the id of 10 (the last event number).  However, if I click the 10th event delete button it will give undefined.

Using Postman I can see that the route works and is deleting correctly. However, when I click any button (but the last), the id always points to the number of the last id and deletes that one.  Further, the last button gives (console.logs) "undefined".

I've found a few similar issues, but they all seem to be a slightly different problem (using a for loop least notably).  I'd greatly appreciate any help in understanding what I'm doing wrong.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

$(document).on("click", ".individualEventButton", handleEventDelete);

$.get("/api/events/", (data) => {
    if (data) {
        const displayData = data;

        displayData.forEach((object) => {
            const eventId = object.id;
            const eventsSection = $("<div>");
            eventsSection.addClass("event");

            $(".individualEventButton").data('id', eventId); //adds data-id to each individual button

            console.log(eventId);

            eventsSection.append("<h2>" + object.title);
            eventsSection.append("<h3>" + object.date);
            eventsSection.append("<p>" + object.description);
            $("#eventsDisplay").append(eventsSection);

            const individualEventButton = $("<button/>", {
                text: "DELETE",
            });

            eventsSection.append(individualEventButton);
            individualEventButton.addClass("individualEventButton");
        });
    } else {
        console.log("ERROR GETTING DATA");
    }
});

function handleEventDelete() {
    const id = $(this).data("id");
   //shows the last created event id if any button is clicked but the last (which shows undefined
    console.log("Show Id: " + id);

    //debugger;
    // Send the DELETE request.
    $.ajax("/api/events/" + id, {
        type: "DELETE"
    }).then(
        function () {
            console.log("deleted id ", id);
            // Reload the page to get the updated list
            location.reload();
        }
    );
}

$("#goToAddEventsPageButton").on("click", ((event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    window.location.replace('/userDashboard');
}));
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You add **id** to the `$(".individualEventButton")`, which means all the buttons with that class, so all your buttons will have the last id except the last one, because the last one was added after your last `$(".individualEventButton").data('id', eventId)` call.

Just delete this line:

```
$(".individualEventButton").data('id', eventId);
```

Change it and put it after / before addClass like this:

```
individualEventButton.addClass("individualEventButton");
individualEventButton.data('id', eventId);
```

It's not about where you put it but the fundamental difference between `individualEventButton.data('id', eventId);` and `$(".individualEventButton").data('id', eventId);`. First adds **id** to the specific element, while the other adds **id** to all elements with specified class.

Comment: That worked perfectly.  Thank you very much for the quick and to the point explanation.